# How to access individual feature map of tensors to keras layers

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I am implementing a custom connection between two different keras layers. The neural network begins something like below:

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D, Flatten, AveragePooling2D
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, Input, Concatenate, Lambda, Add

inputTensor = Input(shape=( 32, 32,1))
stride = 1
c1 = Conv2D(6, kernel_size=[5,5], strides=(stride,stride), padding="valid", input_shape=(32,32,1), 
                  activation = 'tanh')(inputTensor)
s2 = AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2))(c1)
```

Here, I want to apply my custom connection to convolution layer c3 which has an output size of 10*10*16 (that is, 16 filters need to be applied on s2 of size 14*14*6 and get an output of 10*10*16). For this, I need to use `kernal_size = 5*5`, `filers=16`, `stride = 1`, and `padding=valid`.

For my custom connection, instead of using all 6 feature maps of s2 at once, I want to use them individually. I am using `lambda` function as follows:

For example, if I want to use zeroth feature map of s2 and apply 1 filter on it, I am doing as below:

```
group0_a = Lambda(lambda x: x[:,:,:,0], output_shape=lambda x: (x[0], x[1], x[2], 1))(s2)

conv_group0_a = Conv2D(1, kernel_size=[5,5], strides=(stride,stride), padding="valid", activation = 'tanh')(group0_a)
```

Now, I get a error as:

`Input 0 of layer conv2d_10 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received: [None, 14, 14]` which is for `group0_a`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so you can access zeroth feature map of s2 and apply 1 filter on it, you can access it as given below:

```
group0_a = Lambda(lambda x: x[:,:,:,0:1], output_shape=lambda x: (x[0], x[1], x[2], 1))(s2)

conv_group0_a = Conv2D(1, kernel_size=[5,5], strides=(stride,stride), padding="valid", activation = 'tanh')(group0_a)
```

The only thing I did was instead of `x` for `lambda` function as `x[:,:,:,0]`, I am passing it as `x[:,:,:,0:1]`.